# Shortcode that display all product attributes set for a WooCommerce product

Tags: php, function, woocommerce, shortcode, taxonomy-terms

I keep searching for a way to do this, but I can't find anything unfortunately.

I an trying to display all the product's attributes and values, separated by a pipe, in a custom place on the single-product (so for that I was thinking to create a shortcode, so I can place it anywhere I want). the output would be something like this:

*BRAND: RENAULT | MODEL: 12 | YEAR: 1973*

The code on the Woocommerce template *product-attributes.php* lists the attributes of the current product on single-product page, but it will list it with some styles I don't want in a place I don't want.

I want to create a shortcode with that code, which is:

```
<?php foreach ( $product_attributes as $product_attribute_key => $product_attribute ) : ?>
    
            <?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['label'] ); ?>: <?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['value'] ); ?> | 
    
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

How can I create a shortcode with it? I know the general code for a shortcode, but I don't know how to actually integrate the above one in it:

```
function custom_attributes_product_page() { 
 
// integrate the required code

// Output needs to be return
return 
} 
// register shortcode
add_shortcode('custom-attributes', 'custom_attributes_product_page');
```

Would be great if this shortcode would list the attributes and their values separated by a column, like I said above (how to do that?)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following shortcode that will display all product attribute(s) set for a product and their value(s), handling custom attributes too:

```
function get_product_attributes_shortcode($atts ) {
    // Extract shortcode attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id'    => get_the_ID(),
    ), $atts, 'display-attributes' ) );

    global $product;

    if ( ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $id );
    }

    if ( is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
        $html = []; // Initializing

        foreach ( $product->get_attributes() as $attribute => $values ) {
            $attribute_name = wc_attribute_label($values->get_name());
            $attribute_data = $values->get_data();
            $is_taxonomy    = $attribute_data['is_taxonomy'];

            $option_values    = array(); // Initializing

            // For taxonomy product attribute values
            if( $is_taxonomy ) {
                $terms = $values->get_terms(); // Get attribute WP_Terms

                // Loop through attribute WP_Term(s)
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    $term_link       = get_term_link( $term, $attribute );
                    $option_values[] = '<a href="'.$term_link.'">'.$term->name.'</a>';
                }
            }
            // For "custom" product attributes values
            else {
                // Loop through attribute option values
                foreach ( $values->get_options() as $term_name ) {
                    $option_values[] = $term_name;
                }
            }

            $html[] = '<strong>' . $attribute_name . '</strong>: ' . implode(', ', $option_values);
        }

        return '<div class="product-attributes">' . implode(' | ', $html) . '<div>';
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'display-attributes', 'get_product_attributes_shortcode' );
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**USAGE:** `[display-attributes]` or with a defined product Id `[display-attributes id="254"]`

You will get a display like: ***BRAND**: RENAULT | **MODEL**: 12 | **YEAR**: 1973*

If you don't want the linked terms, replace:

```
                    $term_link       = get_term_link( $term, $attribute );
                    $option_values[] = '<a href="'.$term_link.'">'.$term->name.'</a>';
```

by this:

```
                    $option_values[] = $term->name;
```

Comment: thank you so much! you're really awesome and kind to provide such a complete answer

Comment: @whitelord This was easy and quick as I had it mostly somewhere else, I just changed the required output. [This recent thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66215657/change-quantity-input-field-to-a-dropdown-in-woocommerce/66223154#66223154) was a bit more complicated, for example :)

Comment: You need to add a counter to the foreach loop: before the foreach loop you define it like `$count = 0;`… Then inside the foreach loop at the beginning you add `$count++;`… Then at the end inside the foreach loop you add `echo ( $count % 4 ) == 0 ? '<br>' : '';`, that will break the line each 4 attributes. You could [vote 2 or 3 max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730754/loictheaztec?tab=answers&sort=newest) :)

Comment: wonderful! i wanted to ask, @LoicTheAztec, how can this be expanded upon to maintain the default table appearance of attributes, and also to exclude or include specific parent attributes via shortcode?