# Shortcode that display a single product attribute for a WooCommerce product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for a way to display a specific attribute on the single Product page of WooCommerce.
I found this code in the folling topic; [Shortcode that display all product attributes set for a WooCommerce product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66215522/shortcode-that-display-all-product-attributes-set-for-a-woocommerce-product)

```
function get_product_attributes_shortcode($atts ) {
    // Extract shortcode attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id'    => get_the_ID(),
    ), $atts, 'display-attributes' ) );

    global $product;

    if ( ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $id );
    }

    if ( is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
        $html = []; // Initializing

        foreach ( $product->get_attributes() as $attribute => $values ) {
            $attribute_name = wc_attribute_label($values->get_name());
            $attribute_data = $values->get_data();
            $is_taxonomy    = $attribute_data['is_taxonomy'];

            $option_values    = array(); // Initializing

            // For taxonomy product attribute values
            if( $is_taxonomy ) {
                $terms = $values->get_terms(); // Get attribute WP_Terms

                // Loop through attribute WP_Term(s)
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    $term_link       = get_term_link( $term, $attribute );
                    $option_values[] = '<a href="'.$term_link.'">'.$term->name.'</a>';
                }
            }
            // For "custom" product attributes values
            else {
                // Loop through attribute option values
                foreach ( $values->get_options() as $term_name ) {
                    $option_values[] = $term_name;
                }
            }

            $html[] = '<strong>' . $attribute_name . '</strong>: ' . implode(', ', $option_values);
        }

        return '<div class="product-attributes">' . implode(' | ', $html) . '<div>';
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'display-attributes', 'get_product_attributes_shortcode' );
```

I can display all attributes by using the shortcode [display-attributes] but I want to display only one specific attribute (in my case the attribute is "Kunstenaar"). However I don't know how to adjust the code to make this work. Anyone who can help me out?

Comment: you can remove the entire `foreach` loop, and use `$kunstenaar = $product->get_attribute( 'Kunstenaar' );` and use that in the return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need just specific attribute, you don't have to get them all and then go through them. WC have function `get_attribute()` - [documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product.html#method_get_attribute)

```
function get_product_attributes_shortcode( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id'    => get_the_ID(),
    ), $atts, 'display-attributes' ) );

    global $product;

    if ( ! is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $id );
    }
    if ( is_a($product, 'WC_Product') ) {
        $kunstenaar = $product->get_attribute( 'Kunstenaar' );
        return '<div class="product-attributes"><strong>Kunstenaar</strong>: ' . $kunstenaar . '<div>';
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'display-attributes', 'get_product_attributes_shortcode' );
```

Comment: That's great. Thank you! Works as a charm :-).
Any way I can turn the attribute in a link? So people can click on it and see others work from the same kunstenaar? (Artist)